# Not seeing telemetry in azure application insights and application insight resource randomly disappearing

Tags: c#, azure, asp.net-core, azure-application-insights

I'm pretty much new to Azure and Application Insights, but I followed [the steps described here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/asp-net-core) to setup Application Insights in my app. While I can use the Live Metrics feature, and the Overview page also shows me the summarized telemetry, as soon as I want to query the data using the Search feature, it seems like no data was transmitted at all (even though I could view it live via Live Metrics and the overview page showed the summary!)

Also, after some time of creating the Application Insights resource, it appears as if it is deleted. While it still appears in the list of my resources, it just says "resource not found" - I then manually delete them.

I'm thankful for any pointers in the right direction for either issue. I was using an aspnetcore3.1 web app, and the most recent version of the Application Insights SDK.

Thanks and cheers,
CG

Comment: if you keep deleting and recreating resources, that's not a good sign.  "resource not found"  should not be happening.  live metrics is watching the ingestion pipeline and showing it live.  the rest of search/logs/etc will generally be a few minutes behind.  if you see resources disappearing, contact support

Answer (score 0):

Live Metrics - Live Metrics displays the Data Immediately. You don't see historical data here. You can see last 1-2 minutes data only.

Search Feature - It takes 2-5 minutes to reflect the data here Search and rest of the places in the Application Insights.

Live Metrics are displayed instantly, however, the other telemetry is not shown immediately, it might take 2 to 5 minutes. The reason for this is that that Live Metrics Stream and the regular Telemetry use different Application Insight’s Channels